# install mysql on Debian

Tags: debian, sudo, mysql

I want to install mysql on Debian, but I have an error

```
admin@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
[sudo] password for admin: 
admin is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Comment: despite the fact your user is named "admin" they don't have admin rights (no permission to use sudo).  Do you have another way to become the user `root`?

Comment: yes, should I install it as a root, then ?

Comment: yes, in this context `sudo` is just a way to switch to being the root user.  As root, install with just `apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: Not much effort applied to solving the problem there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by [Philip Couling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20140/philip-couling), your `admin` user isn’t allowed to become root using `sudo`. You need to become root in some other way (*e.g.* `su` with the root password), and run

```
apt install mariadb-server
```

In current versions of Debian, `mysql-server` is no longer available, it’s been replaced by `mariadb-server` (which packages [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/), a fork of MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

You have to open a root shell and add your user to the sudo or wheel group:

```
$ su
$ usermod -a -G wheel admin
```

Then edit the /etc/sudoers file in order to make users of the group wheel execute the sudo command:

```
 %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

If there's a # before %wheel you have to delete it and save the file.

Comment: There is no `wheel` group on Debian, I think it's a BSD thing, there is however a `sudo` group which is already allowed in `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: Thank you didn't remember/know that, I don't use Debian and Debian-based distro so often. I've write both sudo and wheel cause I wasn't sure about that

Answer (score -1):

**/etc/sudoers**  is a file which gives root access to a user who is listed in.

In your case admin is not in the sudoers file. You have to edit the sudoers file to enjoy root privileges.

I would recommend visudo to edit the sudoers file because visudo will protect your sudoers file from copping the wrong syntax  to the sudoers.

To allow user to gain full root privileges add this to sudoers.

```
 user_name  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

[visudo wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo#Using_visudo)

Now give a try and install it again