# Error: Unable to retrieve http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/buster/InRelease 403 Forbidden [IP: 23.57.81.191 80]

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, debugging

I'm installing `mysql-server` on my Debian 10.

I used the command: `wget` in the `/tmp`  file,
then `sudo dpkg` command which returned the following response:

```
 acelys @ uno-test-temp: / tmp $ sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt *
    (Reading database ... 46803 files and directories already installed.)
    Preparing to unpack mysql-apt-config_0.8.19-1_all.deb ...
    Unpacking mysql-apt-config (0.8.19-1) to (0.8.19-1) ...
    Setting up mysql-apt-config (0.8.19-1) ...
    Warning: apt-key should not be used in scripts (called from postinst maintainerscript of the package mysql-apt-config)
    OK
```

Then I typed the command: `sudo apt update` and here's the response with errors:

```
acelys @ uno-test-temp: / tmp $ sudo apt update
    Err: 1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease
      403 Forbidden [IP: 23.57.81.191 80]
    Reached: 2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
    Achieved: 3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster / updates InRelease
    Reached: 4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
    Reached: 5 https://packages.sury.org/php buster InRelease
    Reading Package Lists ... Done
    E: Unable to retrieve http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/buster/InRelease 403 Forbidden [IP: 23.57.81.191 80]
    E: The http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease repository is unsigned.
    N: Updates from such a repository cannot be done securely, and are therefore disabled by default.
    N: See the apt-secure (8) man pages for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have searched for lot of articles on Internet, they all talk about doing modifications in the `sources.list` file, but they don't precise what kind of modification I should do.

Here's my `sources.list` file:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.0.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20190706-10:24]/ buster contrib main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.0.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20190706-10:24]/ buster contrib main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib

# buster
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

And here's my `mysql.list` file:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out entries below, but any other modifications may be lost.
# Use command 'dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config' as root for modifications.
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ buster mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ buster mysql-8.0
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ buster mysql-tools
#deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ buster mysql-tools-preview
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ buster mysql-8.0
```

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/589969/117549 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [install mysql on Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589966/install-mysql-on-debian)

Comment: @Greenonline It is not the same problem, this is about mysql repo.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a pretty typical case of a configuration error at the repository server.

```
$ nslookup repo.mysql.com
[...]

Non-authoritative answer:
repo.mysql.com  canonical name = repo.mysql.com.edgekey.net.
repo.mysql.com.edgekey.net      canonical name = e7528.d.akamaiedge.net.
Name:   e7528.d.akamaiedge.net
Address: 23.43.108.232

$ nslookup 23.57.81.191
191.81.57.23.in-addr.arpa       name = a23-57-81-191.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com.
```

It looks like `repo.mysql.com` is served by Akamai's Content Delivery Network, and so DNS queries for it in different locations and at different times will receive different IP addresses as a response, as Akamai attempts to provide the content from their closest available server that has the capacity to provide it.

In your case, though, it appears that the server Akamai directed your request to was faulty. Perhaps it had been allowed to respond to client requests when it was not yet quite finished mirroring the content, or perhaps something else went wrong.

You might want to check the [Akamai services status page](https://www.akamaistatus.com/) and if the problem does not seem to be known there, consider contacting [Akamai Technical Support](http://support.akamai.com/) to report the problem.